# Filter data issue on a data filtering formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I want to sort my list in different sheets as mention value in cell. I want same value formula , that list currently I am uploading excel file in which `>=` formula is working but when I am going to change it to `=`, the formula is not working.

How can I fix it?

File link: https://gofile.io/?c=3WnLZB

formula is 
=IFERROR(INDEX('Car Data'!B$2:B$1156,SMALL(IF('Car Data'!$H$2:$H$1156>='Filtered List'!$A$2,ROW('Car Data'!B$2:B$1156)-ROW('Car Data'!B$2)+1),ROWS('Car Data'!B$2:'Car Data'!B2))),"")

in formula >= used when i change it to = formula returns wrong values

Comment: Please put your formula into the question, many people here wont download your file for security reasons.

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX('Car Data'!B$2:B$1156,SMALL(IF('Car Data'!$H$2:$H$1156>='Filtered List'!$A$2,ROW('Car Data'!B$2:B$1156)-ROW('Car Data'!B$2)+1),ROWS('Car Data'!B$2:'Car Data'!B2))),"")

Comment: there is tho sheets 1 cardata 2 filterd list

Comment: What is the "correct" answer that you're looking for?

Comment: there is 2 sheets   1.car data,2 filteredlist      in sheet named filtered list i want list only entrys that match exact to value which match entered in 'Filtered List'!$A$2 and lookup criteria is in 'Car Data'!$H$2:$H$1156

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your formula.

**Changing this** `=IFERROR(INDEX('Car Data'!B$2:B$1156,SMALL(IF('Car Data'!$H$2:$H$1156>='Filtered List'!$A$2,ROW('Car Data'!B$2:B$1156)-ROW('Car Data'!B$2)+1),ROWS('Car Data'!B$2:'Car Data'!B2))),"")`

**To This**  `=IFERROR(INDEX('Car Data'!B$2:B$1156,SMALL(IF('Car Data'!$H$2:$H$1156='Filtered List'!$A$2,ROW('Car Data'!B$2:B$1156)-ROW('Car Data'!B$2)+1),ROWS('Car Data'!B$2:'Car Data'!B2))),"")`

Will change the logic from anything with greater or higher MPG to anything with a MPG of 45 where their are only two cars. This can be seen in the `CountsIFS` in my screenshot.

[image]